# Difference between ColorDrawable and PaintDrawable

Tags: android, drawable

By just looking at the Android developers documentation of PaintDrawable and ColorDrawable, I can not distinguish the difference between the two. I hope someone can enlighten me with this one...

thanks,
artsylar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A ColorDrawable is a very simple kind of drawable that just fills the canvas with a color. You can set a ColorFilter on a ColorDrawable, but it will be ignored. A PaintDrawable is more complex; it draws a color, but this operation can be modified by a ColorFilter, as well as a Paint object. A ColorDrawable is cheaper to use but more limited in what you can use it for.

Comment: Thanks Ted for your answer. Is PaintDrawable used for drawing rectangle(corner can be rounded or not depending on the radius set) with color filling?

Comment: @artsylar - Yes, a PaintDrawable can do that.